# How to save command stdout to a file?

Tags: rust, io, child-process

I'm writing a function that has a particular logging requirement. I want to capture the output from a `Command::new()` call and save it into a file. I'm just using `echo` here for simplicity's sake.

```
fn sys_command(id: &str) -> u64 {
    let mut cmd = Command::new("echo")
        .args(&[id])
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to echo");

    let stdout = cmd.stdout.as_mut().unwrap();
    let stdout_reader = BufReader::new(stdout);
    // let log_name = format!("./tmp/log/{}.log", id);
    // fs::write(log_name, &stdout_reader);
    println!("{:?}", stdout_reader.buffer());

    cmd.wait().expect("failed to call");
    id.parse::<u64>().unwrap()
}
```

How can I capture the output and save it to a file? I've made a playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5a84d9c65d2c076e1e3fe3e03dce4779). My `println!` call returns `[]`.

Even reading to another buffer prints the wrong value. Below, `sys_command("10")` prints `3`. [Here's](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=285426b779d0d715b3393f699b4f4918) an updated playground.

```
fn sys_command(id: &str) -> u64 {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let mut cmd = Command::new("echo")
        .args(&[id])
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to echo");

    let stdout = cmd.stdout.as_mut().unwrap();
    let mut stdout_reader = BufReader::new(stdout);
    let result = stdout_reader.read_to_string(&mut buffer);
    println!("{:?}", result.unwrap());

    cmd.wait().expect("failed to draw");
    id.parse::<u64>().unwrap()
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of capturing the output in memory and then writing it to a file, you should just redirect the process's output to a file. This is simpler and more efficient.

```rust
    let log_name = format!("./tmp/log/{}.log", id);
    let log = File::create(log_name).expect("failed to open log");

    let mut cmd = Command::new("echo")
        .args(&[id])
        .stdout(log)
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to start echo");

    cmd.wait().expect("failed to finish echo");
```

---

> Even reading to another buffer prints the wrong value. Below, `sys_command("10")` prints `3`.

This is unrelated — `read_to_string()` returns the number of bytes read, not the contents of them, and there are 3 characters: `'1' '0' '\n'`.

Comment: How to share the log file between multiple commands since the command builder takes the ownership?

Comment: @EduBic In that situation you would use [`File::try_clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.try_clone) to duplicate it. Note that when doing this you should [open the file in `append` mode](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.append) so that the different processes are less likely to conflict with each other's writes.